# How to search for questions not containing a certain tag?

Tags: support, search, tag-search

Is it possible to [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) for questions (`is:question`) containing some term and **not** containing a certain tag? Something like:

```
search term is:question ![tag]
```

From time to time I look for improperly tagged questions containing the tag name (product name) inside the question, but missing the tag.

Is there a way to search for questions **not** containing a certain tag?

Comment: Use `mysearchterm is:q -[yourtag]`

Comment: @AzizShaikh, thanks! I missed that documentation.

Comment: So it can be via RSS feed or even a click on search by tags.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

On the [search help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), this is documented:

> To *exclude* results from a tag, term or phrase, prefix it with **-** in your query: **waffles -unicorns** finds posts that mention tasty batter-based breakfasts without including mythical creatures, while **[laurel] -[hardy]** includes only posts pertaining to the first half of the classic comedy couple.

Comment: In a tab filter it's `waffles not unicorns` instead.

Answer (score 6):

For searches, you can apply a minus to a tag, so you could [search for `[java] -[android]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+-android) and pull a feed from that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I see a lot of questions that should one or both of these tags, but don't. But we need more people to edit tags for that to happen.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the [new navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate), you can easily exclude tags, with a query like "*java not android not gradle*"

You can also "save" the query as a saved tab, so you can get back to it quickly:

[image]