# Add negative searching to Advanced Search Tips

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, user-interface

I had a half composed meta question about requesting the ability to filter searches for questions that didn't have a particular tag when I thought to double check the [searching help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).  (For the record, use `-[the-tag]`.)

I'd (wrongly) guessed a couple of syntaxes (`[-the-tag]` and `[^the-tag]`) and read the Advanced Search Tips pane before deciding that the feature didn't exist.
[image: The Stack Overflow advanced search pane]

Adding an extra line or two to this pane, perhaps

```
exclude    -[tag]
           -apples
```

would have quickly let me know that this feature existed.

I think it would be useful to others too; if you agree, upvote this question.

---

As ekhumuro points out, the advice is available on the page linked from the Advanced Search Tips pane.  (This was how I eventually found the feature.)  Since not everyone will click through (I suspect more people won't click than will), I feel that this constitutes unnecessarily hiding the feature.

Comment: +1. And I would gladly see a `not` operator for free phrases as well.

Comment: The advice at the bottom of the Advanced Search Tips links to the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) which describes this feature (amongst many others). Why have you trimmed it from the screenshot in your question?

Comment: @ekhumoro Screenshot updated, Q edited to respond.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Richie, like I, probably assumed that the broad outlines were complete in the overview, and that the details would merely flesh those out. That's not the case, and it took both of us longer than it should have to realize that the search tips are, as it were, compressed lossily.

Comment: [I was lame enough](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271236/960757) to not follow the help page when I could not find it in that side bar.

Comment: I'm seeing how this could be annoying. Taking a look at what I can do now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. I've added a section on exclusions to the advanced search tips bar on the right side of the results page. You'll see it go live in just a few moments.

Comment: Great! -[status-declined]