# How to combine OR and EXCLUDE in searches?

Tags: bug, search

I am trying to search for specific tags but excluding others. I have reviewed [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271236/how-to-search-for-questions-not-containing-a-certain-tag) and the [search help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) but am running into an issue combining the OR operator with excluding tags.

When I run this search:

> [[java] -[android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+-android)

I get expected results with the `[java]` tag being present and `[android]` excluded.

However, if I want to search for either the `[java]` OR `[javafx]` tags but still exclude `[android]`, it fails and includes `[android]` questions:

> [[java] or [javafx] -[android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+javafx+-android)

This issue does not seem to affect the AND operator as this yields expected results as well:

> [[java] and [javafx] -[android]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D%20and%20%5Bjavafx%5D%20-%5Bandroid%5D)

Could someone explain why and how to work around it?

Comment: I think that was only possible with the new-nav that is now gone.

Comment: If your search goal allows for having stale data for up to a week, you can use SEDE: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/863359

Comment: My goal isn't to have stale data, but to filter the questions to ones I could actually help with.

Comment: Your only hope is the Stack API then: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&nottagged=android&tagged=java%3Bjavafx&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true but you'll have to do an aggregate of  results yourself

Comment: Seems strange they would remove that functionality but not update their help section; bummer. Thanks for the info, though.

Comment: [`[java] -[android] or [javafx] -[android]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=%5bjava%5d%20-%5bandroid%5d%20or%20%5bjavafx%5d%20-%5bandroid%5d) seems to work

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With a small change this search excludes [android].

> [[java] or [javafx] -[android] is:q](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bjava%5D%20or%20%5Bjavafx%5D%20-%5Bandroid%5D%20is%3Aq)

Comment: Interesting ... so the query language does support this, but with a minor tweak. Seems like a design flaw or a bug to me. Thank you, @niton!

Comment: This has been around for a while: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289388/cant-search-multiple-tags-but-exclude-a-specific-tag - essentially, the solution is to use some operator that *doesn't* work for tag filters, thus falling back on the full search engine. It would be nice to make this a bit more seamless.